# Delete/Insert Last Record of a Table with an Auto Increment Key in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, insert, auto-increment

I have a table with an auto increment primary key in sqlite. Lets say that I have these records in my table:

```
1 hi
2 hello
3 bye
4 goodbye
```

if I delete bye and add another record, the new record's id is going to be 5. But if I delete goodbye and add a new one, the new record's id is going to be 4. With this I will loose track of the last record if being deleted and added over and over. Is there anyway I could make the new record to be 5 instead of 4?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a column declared as [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).

What you want instead is [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

---

Example:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 2;
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable;
1
3
```

Comment: thanx but in sqlite, a primary key by defauls is autoincrement. I don't have a problem with making it autoincrement. my problem is with deleting the last row and inserting again.

Comment: When you explicitly write `AUTOINCREMENT`, SQLite does not reuse deleted IDs. (Read the documentation!)

Comment: but what I see is not what you are saying. It replaces the last one if its deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT definition:

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually the one more than the largest ROWID currently
>   in use.This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.

So you should forget about INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT to achive what you  want.Instead you can create a column myKey, and set the value of this column with an static method that holds the number of inserted row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you just have to edit the record and state the record number that it was originally. Easy to do in PHPmyadmin, but not in code.